# Rails 3: How to prevent image caching when the image is specified in the CSS file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, browser-cache, image-caching

Consider the following CSS:

```
.my_class {
  background-image: url(/images/sprites.png);
}
```

Sometimes I change `sprites.png` by adding new sprites to it, so I don't want the browser to cache it.

One idea I thought of is to add `style="background-image: url(/images/sprites.png?<random_number_here>)"` to all elements with class `my_class`, and delete the CSS code above.
But, I don't like this solution because of maintainability issues (if for example the file name changes, I have to change it in many places, rather than a single CSS).

What other solutions exist to this problem ?

Comment: Why not just expire the cache when there is a change? A client should query the server and see if the content is modified before displaying the local cache.

Comment: @Devin: How could I expire the cache ?

Comment: Rails should append a timestamp to assets automatically, See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html under the heading "Customizing the asset path"

Comment: @Devin M While it's true that rails provides a timestamp for css and image links, as far as I know this doesn't apply to css `background-image` links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around this is to [add a version string to your style directory](http://www.sitepoint.com/overcome-cache-conundrums/).

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css.1000/styles.css" type="text/css" />`

Ensure that your css uses URLs relative to that directory. (In this example, the image directory for css links is `css.1000/image`)

```
.my_class {
    background-image: url(images/sprites.png);
}
```

Then, use `mod_rewrite` to add a rewrite rule to the `.htaccess` file in your site's root folder, this will make any numerical path `/css.1000/styles.css` point to `/css/styles.css` on the server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule css[\.][0-9]+/(.*)$ css/$1 [L]
```

Any time you change your site's assets, you change the version number of the folder in your stylesheet link.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest one of these two techniques:

Use Javascript to perform the cache update technique.

```
 $('.my_class').ready(function() { 
   $(this).css('background-image', 
    $(this).css('background-image') + "?" + Math.random());
 }
```

Use specific server content-control for your given page.  This is from [this StackExchange answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/23157/setting-expires-headers-for-static-content-served-from-nginx) for nginx ([similar techniques exist in apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/235242/how-to-set-no-cache-headers-to-a-specific-url-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)):

```
 server {
   ...

   location = /images/sprites.png {
    expires 1d;
   }
   ...
 }
```

These will both work to help mitigate your issue.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use rails asset pipeline (i.e. rails > 3.1), and it automatically does this for you via the fingerprinting mechanism:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark

Rename your mycss.css to mycss.css.erb and specify the images as:

`.my_class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }`

Rails will take care of everything else (you need to enable asset precompilation as well).